# Arduino. While loop with a timer inside an infinite loop

Tags: c++, arduino

I have an arduino leonardo and I would like to make a while loop with a given work boundary inside an infinite loop. That is, an infinite loop repeats a ten-minute while loop. Is it possible to do it?

```
#include <Mouse.h>
#include <Keyboard.h>

#define timer 5 // running time of the while loop in minutes

void setup(){
  Mouse.begin();
  randomSeed(analogRead(0) + analogRead(1));
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop(){
  
  if(!digitalRead(3)){ // starting work through the button click on pin 3
  delay(200);
    doAction();
  }
}

void doAction () {
  int last_keyboard = millis();
  int start_time = millis();
  while(millis()-start_time<=timer*60000){
  
  // action here

  }
  delay(100);
  }
}
```

Comment: what happened when you compiled your code and executed the program?

Comment: The required actions were performed within 5 minutes. Then the arduino stopped and the repeated execution of the five-minute cycle did not happen.

Comment: Use `unsigned long` instead of `int` as type of `last_keyboard` and `start_time`, maybe a problem related to integer overflow.

Comment: You could take a look at [TimerInterrupt](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/timerinterrupt/) and use the hardware instead of the software. This is a neat solution to create precise timing intervals.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  But your code needs work to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Arduino API reference for the [millis()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) function, it returns an **unsigned long** which is necessary to hold "the number of milliseconds passed since the Arduino board began running the current program".  The ATmega boards have [16-bit integers](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/) so your problem is integer overflow. Your ints are too small. Use **unsigned long** instead. Possibly with UL added to 60000, to specify an unsigned long number.